# RPN Algorithm Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, rpn

I have already changed user input to postFix 
Example, 5 * 3 + 2 * 5 = 53*25*+

postfix is in an NSMutableArray called resultOutput.
I am trying to implement the calculation.

My logic is resultOutput must have only one element in the end. (Result)
and then I loop with for() if resultOutput[i] is equal to operators, then do calculation i-2 and i-1. 
And then insert result in i+1 and remove those 2 numbers. Then i = i -2;.

Here is my code.

while (resultOutput.count > 1) {

```
    for (int i = 0; i < resultOutput.count; i++) {

        if ([[operatorPrecedence allKeys]containsObject:resultOutput[i]]) {

            NSRange range    = NSMakeRange(i-2, i);

            numberOne   =   [resultOutput[i-2]integerValue];
            numberTwo   =   [resultOutput[i-1]integerValue];
            mySign      =   resultOutput[i];
            result      =   [self calcNumbers:mySign andNumberOne:numberOne andNumberTwo:numberTwo];

            [resultOutput removeObjectsInRange:range];
            i = i - 2;
            [resultOutput insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:result] atIndex:i];
        }

    }

}
```

got index out of bound error. 
My logic is wrong in somewhere? Thanks in advance. I am new to programming.

Comment: 1. Please post the original and complete error message. 2. Use a debugger to go step by step through the code and then ask a concrete Q, if there is still one.

Comment: Thanks mate. I got it.. I have never tried debugging before and I did it for the first time. The thing is i am wrong at NSRange (start location, length). So it becomes out of bound. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem and great that you learned something you can use in future instead of solely solving the specific problem.